# How to make "Highest Rated" the default on yelp.com

Tags: sorting, yelp.com

Whenever I start a new search on Yelp, it sets the sort order to "Best Match." Is there a way to have the default be "Highest Rated" instead?

If I can't figure anything else out, I'll set up a keyword search in my browser with `&sortby=rating` included in the URL, but some way to make this universal for my logged-in Yelp account would be friendlier.